# What is the purpose of X-Cloud-Trace-Context?

Tags: http, post, header, python-requests, put

I was practicing some HTTP Post requests with a post-test server (ptsv2.com).

After a successful post, I can see the request body and headers etc. on the site.

There is one value that I am unsure about:

```
X-Cloud-Trace-Context
```

What is this for?? I understand the rest of header data, but I can't seem to find a good explanation on that one part.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

`X-Cloud-Trace-Context` is a header from Google Cloud Platform to identify the current request.

It is particularly useful for correlating logs. As per documentation (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/writing-application-logs), correlation has to be done manually. This post explains in detail how to do it: https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/google-app-engine/app-engine-standard-python37-correlate-application-log-with-request-log/

Comment: Is it reliable, I noticed when we're under botnet some headers from cloud flare don't get sent.